# Delete agent if no transporter route is found

Tags: anylogic

I am creating an Anylogic pathfinding simulation. I create an Agent called Box with source and transport it with moveByTransporter from one random Node to another. I am using JGraphT to convert the network to a Graph and use DijkstraShortestPath algorithm to find a path. Now my problem: If there is no path to the Box, I want to delete it and send the transporter back to its home location.

I tried using `unit.currentBlock().remove(unit);` and `agent.currentBlock().remove(agent);` but get this error:

```
> `java.lang.RuntimeException: root.<population>[1]:
Agent (Unit#2[root.moveByTransporter1]:null) can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict: root.moveByTransporter1.seize.release.release.unitWrapUpEnter and root.moveByTransporter1
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.AgentExtensionImpl.error(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ExtEntityImpl.b(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Enter.take(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Release.b(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceUnitWrapUpTask.onStart(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceUnitExtension.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourceUnitExtension.d(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool$1.a(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ResourcePool$1.action(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$m.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.k(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.bi(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$m.run(Unknown Source)`
```

[Anylogic blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HQ6Z.png)
Is there a way to do this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: probably easiest if you check this before entering the Transporter block and delete the agent before it even starts the transporting.